# Adapting OpenGL render context on remote desktop connection attempt

Tags: c++, windows, opengl, remote-desktop

We have an application which uses an OpenGL render context in a subwindow to display a large bitmap. However, when a user remotely connects to a box running this app, the openGL display stops working, most likely due to the reduced texture resolution.

While we can detect the remote desktop connection starting/ending using WTS_REMOTE_CONNECT, the openGL context does not switch to the virtual driver when trying to determine the new max texture resolution.

Completely restarting the openGL subthread hangs on ChoosePixelFormat, this wont return until I am logged in locally again, otherwise this would be the "bad" solution.

Comment: Does the program work when the remote user launches it?

Comment: Yup, the only issue is having the running program surviving the switch from local user to remote user, without having to restart it.

If it is started when connected remotely, then logging in locally, the display continues to function as well.

Answer (score 0):

It seam that application is badly written.

Code that is responsible for detecting context changes and reacting to them accordingly, do not exist or is buggy. Any way, you can not do much, unless you have access to source code. Also you can report is as a bug to vendor or provider from whom you bought it.